# Problems in getting the derivatives of the batch normalization layer

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, neural-networks

I'm working on understanding the math used in the batch normalization layer in the CNN and found the original paper discussing this trick: [Batch Normalization: Accelerating Deep Network Training by Reducing Internal Covariate Shift](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf)

The backpropagation process goes like this:
$$
\frac{\partial l}{\partial \hat x_i} = \frac{\partial l}{\partial y_i}\cdot \gamma \\
\frac{\partial l}{\partial \sigma_{\cal B}^2} = \sum_{i=1}^m\frac{\partial l}{\partial \hat x_i}\cdot (x_i - \mu_{\cal B})\cdot \frac{-1}2(\sigma_{\cal B}^2 + \epsilon)^{-3/2} \\
\frac{\partial l}{\partial \mu_{\cal B}} = \left(\sum_{i = 1}^m\frac{\partial l}{\partial \hat x_i}\cdot \frac{-1}{\sqrt{\sigma_{\cal B}^2 + \epsilon}}\right) + \frac{\partial l}{\partial \sigma^2_{\cal B}}\cdot\frac{\sum_{i=1}^m - 2(x_i - \mu_{\cal B})}{m} \\
\frac{\partial l}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\partial l}{\partial \hat x_i} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma^2_{\cal B} + \epsilon}} + \frac{\partial l}{\partial \sigma^2_{\cal B}}\cdot \frac{2(x_i - \mu_{\cal B})}{m} + \frac{\partial l}{\partial \mu_{\cal B}}\cdot \frac 1 m
$$
My question is: since
$$\hat x_i = \frac{x_i - \mu_{\cal B}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{\cal B}^2 + \epsilon}} = \frac{x_i - \mu_{\cal B}(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_i, \cdots, x_m)}{\sqrt{\sigma_{\cal B}^2(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_i, \cdots, x_m) + \epsilon}} \\
\frac{\partial \mu_{\cal B}}{\partial x_i} = \frac1m \\
\frac{\partial \sigma_{\cal B}^2}{\partial x_i} = \frac{2(x_i - \mu_{\cal B})}{m}
$$

Why couldn't I compute $\frac{\partial l}{\partial x_i}$ directly  by
$$
\frac{\partial l}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\partial l}{\partial \hat x_i}\cdot \frac{\partial \hat x_i}{\partial x_i} \\
\frac{\partial \hat x_i}{\partial x_i} = \frac{(1 - 1/m)\sqrt{\sigma^2_{\cal B} + \epsilon} - (x_i - \mu_{\cal B})\cdot \frac 1 2 \cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma_{\cal B}^2+ \epsilon}}\cdot \frac{2(x_i - \mu_{\cal B})}{m}}{\sigma^2_{\cal B} + \epsilon}$$

The summarization component in the partial derivatives w.r.t. mean and variance will be lost. What's wrong?

Comment: Can you summarize how the loss function $l$ is defined?

Comment: If I'm not getting the idea behind batch normalization wrong, the loss function should be the summarization of all the errors given samples $(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_m)$ in a batch? BTW, does the definition of loss function really matter in this question?

Comment: The [computational graph](https://medium.com/@raytroop/computational-graph-for-batch-normalization-cdefc50199d4). However, it does not answer my question :(

Comment: I think it is crucial to see how the loss depends on the variables.

Comment: You absolutely can do the computation using the proposed direct method -- and if you do it carefully and correctly, you will obtain the **same** result as the standard method.

Comment: I've updated my wrong solution to the partial derivatives. Could you please tell me which part is not correct?